# Android: null pointer exception inside in SmsManager sendTextMessage

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, sms, smsmanager

Got crash from user's device (could not reproduce by myself) during sending SMS via `smsManager.sendTextMessage`
User's device is Sony Xperia Z2, Android 5.1.1

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'java.lang.String android.content.pm.PackageInfo.packageName' on a null object reference
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1562)
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1505)
       at com.android.internal.telephony.ISms$Stub$Proxy.sendTextForSubscriber(ISms.java:1306)
       at android.telephony.SmsManager.sendTextMessage(SmsManager.java:270)
       at com.xabber.android.ui.sms.SmsVerificationManager.requestPhoneNumberVerification(SmsVerificationManager.java:80)
       at com.xabber.android.ui.RegistrationFragment1PhoneAndName.onNextPressed(RegistrationFragment1PhoneAndName.java:193)
       at com.xabber.android.ui.RegistrationActivity.onClick(RegistrationActivity.java:122)
       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4856)
       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19956)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5373)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)
```

SMS sending works excellent on my device and several others. Seems, that it is Android bug.

I could not find anything similar except for https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/automate-user/8gyfmMvPYDY
but they didn't solve it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: no, it happens inside in Android code, I do not access package name

Comment: same happened to me, version 5.1.1, couldn't reproduce it

Comment: Automate developer here. Does your app send from an non-standard process? From a non-main thread? Does the app use sharedUserId?